# How does a KML file help in loading maps in the Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

> KML uses a tag-based structure with nested elements and attributes and is based on the XML standard.

So, KML is basically a "text" file, it doesn't contain the maps.

How does Google Earth use KML files to show maps? **Does it treat KML file as an "index" to know which of its maps to pick when user presses x button?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KML is an XML language used to annotate the Earth with points, lines, polygons, 3d models, and overlays.

As an analogy, HTML is a language to structure and represent textual information and multi-media in a 2-D document context within a web browser. Likewise, KML is a language to structure and represent geospatial and temporal entities on a map and show in "earth browsers" such as Google Earth.

Specifically KML allows you to :

- Specify icons and labels to identify locations on the surface of the planet
- Create different camera positions to define unique views for geographic features
- Define image overlays to attach to ground or screen
- Define styles to specify KML feature appearance
- Organize KML features into hierarchies
- Locate and update retrieved KML documents from local or remote network locations

KML is a structured format of data that tells Google Earth how to display the data (point, line, icons, colors, styles, etc.) and where to draw it (longitude and latitude optionally at a given altitude). KML is simply a data exchange format.

Here's a simple KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
  <name>New York City</name>
  <description>New York City</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-74.006393,40.714172</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

As an "index", a KML file by default will load at the center point that covers all includes features in the KML, but that can be overridden if a *[LookAt](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat)* or *[Camera](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#camera)* is defined. If you click on a Placemark it will fly to that feature as defined by its coordinates.

Clicking on such a placemark in Google Earth will fly to that location, which for the example above happens to be New York City.

KML is a "text" file that can also be packaged and distributed in a "[KMZ](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives)" file, which is a ZIP file with *.kmz* file extension.

More details about KML can be in the [OGC KML Standard # 07-147r2](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml) .